# Sorting a Table with Date String

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a better way to build the date into a string. I need the date as a string so I can apply sorting to my table column....Looking for more efficiency... The output looks like this ( e.g. 20151104 )

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

// date into string
$year = date('Y', strtotime($row['DOE']));
$month = date('m', strtotime($row['DOE']));
$day = date('d', strtotime($row['DOE']));

$strdat=($year . $month . $day);


  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='ws' data-sort-value='" . $strdat . "'>" . $row['DOE'] . " </td>";
```

thanks

Comment: Just a thought, but you can break out the call to strtotime() and only call it once, looks as though you call it multiple times to issue the call to date().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = date('Ymd', strtotime($row['DOE']));
```

Or juste use :

```
$date = strtotime($row['DOE']);
```

since it give you the timestamp (an integer) and will be equally efficient with less code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before, It is easily solved

```
  $time = time();  //You can replace it with your timestamp
  $strtime = gmdate("Y-m-d", $time);

  $arr = explode('-',$strtime);

  $days = $arr[2];
  $months = $arr[1];
  $years = $arr[0];
```

Of course there are several other methods than this, but if you don't remember all the php functions this will work perfect for you .